# random numbers in android animation xml file

Tags: android

I am trying to get my animation to go to a somewhat random location every time it occurs.

Here is my xml

```
<translate
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="randomNumber%"
    android:fromYDelta="0%"
    android:toYDelta="-200%"
    android:duration="3000"
    android:zAdjustment="top" />
```

As you can see, I want the value for the XDelta to be random. But if I use

```
    function random():void{
//calculating the random number
randomNumber = Math.round(Math.random() * (20));

    }
```

I get a string and as I have read the XDelta only accepts floats or percents??? What is the correction? is there an easy way to change the string to a float/percent? any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** As cdhabecker succinctly put it in the comments:

> You can't use an XML definition for an animation that you want to
>   change dynamically; the XML is static. In your app code, create new
>   TranslateAnimations and then run them on your view via
>   View.startAnimation()

See below for answers to your direct questions on rounding, which aren't directly applicable to solving your immediate problem, yet informative as you progress to using `TranslateAnimation` correctly.

From the Android documentation on [translate](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#translate-element):

> A vertical and/or horizontal motion. Supports the following attributes
>   in any of the following three formats: values from -100 to 100 ending
>   with "%", indicating a percentage relative to itself; values from -100
>   to 100 ending in "%p", indicating a percentage relative to its parent;
>   a float value with no suffix, indicating an absolute value.

Math.random returns a double between 0.0 and 1.0, which you are multiplying by 20, yielding a number between 0.0 and 20.0. Then you are using Math.round to turn that value into a long, giving you an integer between 0 and 19, inclusive.

What data type is randomNumber and what are you doing with it?

It seems to me that if you want to programmatically calculate the animation values, you should just instantiate an instance of [TranslateAnimation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html) and just call `start()` on it.

Comment: Raul didn't say so explicitly, but you can't use an XML definition for an animation that you want to change dynamically; the XML is static. In your app code, create new TranslateAnimations and then run them on your view via View.startAnimation().

Comment: yes... Of course! xml is static, and that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it... and of course it' super simple!

```
    ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    final ImageView stopImage=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);


    stopImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            mpButtonClick.start();

            TranslateAnimation  anim = new TranslateAnimation(0f,250 + Math.round(Math.random() * (-700)),0f,-300f);

               anim.setDuration(1800);
               anim.setRepeatCount(0);

           stopImage.startAnimation(anim);

        }
    });
```

Exactly what i wanted, you touch the image and it flies (randomly) away out the top of the screen. Thanks guys for pointing me in the right direction!